# jdeveloper creating integrated weblogic domain hangs

Tags: windows, weblogic, jdeveloper

I install jdeveloper on my windows machine and select default setup. I start the weblogic server getting the set password window. I set the password and leave the domain blank as this worked on a different windows machine. The last thing I see in the console is the following message and nothing happens beyond that:

```
[Waiting for the domain to finish building...]
[08:18:10 AM] Creating Integrated Weblogic domain...
```

there is an extensions error in the extensions log stating `Error:failed to create stream factory class oracle.ide.net.IdeWrapperURLStreamHandlerFactory`, but I have gotten past this point with that error on a different machine.

I looked in the `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.62.29` folder for any files named `*.log` and nothing. Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Check what version of java you are using. Do you have a longer stacktrace for the error you can post?

Comment: where would I look for a stack trace? 

I receive no feedback at all. the java version is the one that came bundled with jdeveloper "C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the DefaultDomain folder from you system11.1.1.6.x.x.x folder to get of the unfinished installation of the internal wls. Then try to create the internal wls again, this time setting the domain. See if this created the wls. 
Funny that you don't see any log files. If I remember right the is one written. path is print out in the log messages window where you saw the other message.

Make sure that firewalls are turned off or set appropriately because windows firewall sometimes blocks without the popup notifications one would expect.

Comment: I did what you suggested. same issue.

Comment: I am beginning to think that using integrated wls is not a good idea. I have had a ton of problems starting applications from jdeveloper by selecting run in the menu bar. Including the following related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906063

Comment: for some reason deleting everything and installing 11.1.1.7 and using localhost in the initial weblogic configuration screen worked. I don't know if there is a bug with 11.1.1.6 or what.

Comment: It is working fine, you just need to take some time, it took about half an hour to creating this domain. Of course if you can do it separately, then you will be more understanding the workflow.